# Is it a good idea to remove iml file when cleaning the project?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I encountered an issue that my module `iml` file corruped so compilation always fails. Clean Project doesn't resolve the error. Finally I deleted the `iml` and Android Studio regenerates it, then everything goes back to normal.

Considering iml will be regenerated and should not be added to version control system, is it a good idea to add a step in Gradle to remove the file when I run "Clean Project"?

Answer (score 1):

As a static iml file does not work for your favor, I think you can modify clean task to remove the certain iml file, and regenerate it every time.

Here is something what I did: [commit ref](https://github.com/chenrui333/gs-spring-boot/commit/2f2c8f52d6cab488d29f87e97f8f3bde2cca2725)

I can run `./gradlew clean idea` to always regenerate the `initial.iml` file,

or if I run with `./gradlew clean build`, my Intellij project can live without that `initial.iml` file.

Let me know if this works.